# Problem to understand Borel-Cantelli Lemma

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, limsup-and-liminf, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I needed to prove the Borel-Cantelli lemma, which states that

> If $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(A_n) < \infty \implies P(\limsup A_n) =
> > 0,$$
>
> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(A_n) = \infty \implies P(\limsup A_n) = 1 $$

I could understannd the proof, but I am struggling with a detail:

If this probability is defined in a probability space, say $(\Omega, \mathbb{F}, P) $, then $ \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \in \mathbb{F} $. Then how is the following equality possible? $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(A_n) = \infty $$

I believe it is due to the fact that $$ P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\right) \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(A_n) $$

which makes possible for $ \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \in \mathbb{F} $ and still the sum of the probabilities not to be convergent. But it's still quite misty to me, I can't imagine an example where the sum of the probabilities would not be convergent. Could you give me one example?

Thank you!

Comment: Just set $A_n = A$ for all $n$ and take $A$ such that $P(A) > 0$.  For example, let $A$ be the event of rolling a 1 on a 6-sided die.

Comment: It's not clear why the second assertion is true, if $A_n = A$.

Comment: in second equation , is need event be independent?

Comment: I don't know if [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/279486) might be helpful.

Comment: let toss a coin, $\{A_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ $A_n$ is the outcome of coin that is $H$ or $T$.  $A_n$ are independent

Comment: @masoud yes they need to be independent. That's very important!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let $\{A_n,n\geq 1\}$ is a sequence of tossing a coin. define $A_n$ that we observe $\{H \}$ in n-Th .

$ lim sup A_n$ ,That means the event that observe infinitely many of $H$,. so  and $P(lim sup A_n)=1$ .

according to lemma $\sum p(A_n)=\infty$ and the results are same.

let $B_n$ be that not any of $A_1,\cdots ,A_n$ be "H".  $P(lim sup B_n)=0$

also $\sum (\frac{1}{2^n}) < \infty$ so the results are same

Comment: Waht is $Th$ in your first paragraph?

Comment: i am not good in english. i means, the resulte of the cion tossing in the experiment with number n. like 5th